# Verification failed for Tuya IOS sdk in Flutter after Integration

Tags: ios, flutter, integration, verification, tuya

I have integrated Tuya SDK in my flutter app for iOS. But while signing in, i am getting error saying "Verification failed".

Following is the detailed description of error

```
Error Domain=com.thing.www Code=1501 "Permission Verification Failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission Verification Failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=SING_VALIDATE_FALED}
```

Here is the code in AppDelegate file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import ThingSmartBaseKit

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    
private var flutterResult: FlutterResult?

    override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
     
      ThingSmartSDK.sharedInstance().start(withAppKey: AppKeys.appKey, secretKey: AppKeys.secretKey)
    #if DEBUG
       ThingSmartSDK.sharedInstance()?.debugMode = true
    #else
    #endif
      
      setMethodChannels()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
   
    func setMethodChannels() {
        if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
            let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
                name: "NativeBridgeChannel",
                binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
            
            channel.setMethodCallHandler { [weak self]
                (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                self?.flutterResult = result
                if call.method == "test" {
                    self?.tuyaLogin(result: result)
                } else {
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tuyaLogin(result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        ThingSmartUser.sharedInstance().loginOrRegister(withCountryCode: "+92", uid: "unkn@gmail.com", password: "1234567", createHome: false) { (res) in
            result("Logged In")
            
        } failure: { (error) in
            let errorMessage = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
            print(error.debugDescription)
            result(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I have double checked the BundleId, AppSecret key & App key, but again i am getting the same error.